# How to turn generic array into a record while retaining literal type at each index?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assume

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const bob = {
  name: "Bob",
  age: 32,
} as const;

const alice = {
  name: "Alice",
  age: 43,
} as const;
```

I want to write a function that takes a Person and turns it into an object where the keys are the Persons name and the values are the Person object.

If I want to do this with one person I can do

```js
function getPerson<T extends Person>(personOption: T) {
  let person = {} as Record<(typeof personOption)["name"], typeof personOption>;
  return person;
}

const person = getPerson(bob); // Bob: {name: "Bob", age: 32}
const personName = person.Bob.name; // Bob
```

But if I want to extend this functionality to take in an array of people the literal types don't translate to their respective index

```js
function getPeople<T extends Person>(peopleOptions: T[]) {
  let people = {} as Record<
    (typeof peopleOptions)[number]["name"],
    (typeof peopleOptions)[number]
  >;
  return people;
}

const people = getPeople([bob, alice]);

const bobName = people.Bob.name; // Bob | Alice
const aliceName = people.Alice.name; // Bob | Alice
```

How can I rewrite this so that `bobName` returns "Bob" and `aliceName` returns "Alice" not the union of the two?

Comment: _"I want to write a function that takes a Person and turns it into an object where the keys are the Persons name"_ - that sounds like a bad idea (as it introduces dynamism to your types... which kinda defeats the point of using TypeScript for static-types in the first place) - may I ask **why** you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBQ24w) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @SamScolari were you the one who up voted my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we will use the following utility type to make the types shown in IDE more readable (without `&`):

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R ? {
  [K in keyof R]: R[K]
} : never
```

For the actual implementation, we will use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to traverse through the array and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to create the object where the keys are names of the array's elements:

```
type MapPeople<T extends readonly Person[]> = Prettify<{
  [K in T[number] as K['name']]: K
}>
```

Usage:

```
function getPeople<T extends readonly Person[]>(peopleOptions: T) {
  let people = {} as MapPeople<T>;
  return people;
}
```

Testing:

```
// const people: {
//     Bob: {
//         readonly name: "Bob";
//         readonly age: 32;
//     };
//     Alice: {
//         readonly name: "Alice";
//         readonly age: 43;
//     };
// }
const people = getPeople([bob, alice]);

const bobName = people.Bob.name; // Bob
const aliceName = people.Alice.name; // Alice
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)